# How do see all the users who arent in an active game with the current user

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to challenge players who arent currently in an active game yet with the current user.

The current tables i'm using are as following :

```
Game {
game_id       int primary key
player1       varchar(20)
player2       varchar(20)
game_status   varchar(10)}


Account{
name          varchar(20) primary key
password      varchar(15)}
```

In the "Game" table, player1 as well as player2 are both foreign keys to account:name. What i want is to select all account:name rows that arent yet in a game with the current user(the user who is logged in) that isn't finished yet(game_stasus = 'finished'). The current user may either be under game:player1 or game:player2, that should not matter.

I was wondering is you could easily do this with an exists subquery? Honestly I am out of ideas and I hope you could help me out.

Comment: Show us your best try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `NOT IN` query with nested `UNION` clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM account a 
WHERE a.name NOT IN (

    SELECT player1 
    FROM game WHERE player2 = <current_user> AND game_status = 'active'

    UNION

    SELECT player2 
    FROM game WHERE player1 = <current_user> AND game_status = 'active'
)
OR NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM game WHERE player1 = a.name OR player2 = a.name
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if i add the or not exists subquery, wouldnt that mean i wont get any records at all? seeing player1 and player2 are always a.name?

Comment: It will give you all the players which are not into any game.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use a LEFT JOIN query myself, but that is mostly stylistic and historical, coming from a previous database where NOT IN was significantly slower. I think they are pretty much the same for modern SQL Server instances.

```
SELECT name
FROM Account
LEFT JOIN Game g1
    ON g1.Player1 = name
    AND player2 = <current_user> 
    AND game_status = 'active'
LEFT JOIN Game g2
    ON g1.Player1 = name
    AND player1 = <current_user> 
    AND game_status = 'active'
WHERE g1.Player1 is null
    AND g2.Player2 is null
```